# Iterate on a data set and insert in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

What I would like to do is something along these lines:

1. Select ids from `tableA`
2. Iterate on the ids and for each one do an insert in `tableB`.

Example: Lets assume the select from `tableA` yields `(123, 1452, 456)`
I would then like to programmatically do an insert for each

```
INSERT INTO 
    tableB (id, something, somethingElse)
VALUES
    (123, 'asdasd', 'asdasdasd')
    (1452, 'asdasd', 'asdasdasd')
    (456, 'asdasd', 'asdasdasd')
```

The contents of `something` and `somethingElse` are irrelevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can make use of MySql cursors,here is an example

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE Id INT;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM TableA;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO Id;
IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

  insert into tableB (id, something, somethingElse) VALUES (Id, 'asdasd', 'asdasdasd');

END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
```

you can find more about it
 [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to think "loop" or "iterate" when working with SQL. Find a way to write an SQL command that will do what you need by working on the whole set. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id, something, somethingElse)
SELECT id, 'asdasd', 'asdasdasd'
FROM TableA
```